# Better way to pull N queries after limit with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, here is my problem.

I've got a database which imports data from CSV that is huge. It contains around 32000 entries, but has around 200 header columns, hence the standard select is slow.

When I do:

`MyModel.all` or `MyModel.eager_load.all` it takes anywhere from 45 seconds up to a minute to load all the entries.

The idea was to use limit to pull maybe 1000 entries like:

```rb
my_model = MyModel.limit(1000)
```

This way I can get the last id like:

```rb
last_id = my_model.last.id
```

To load next 1000 queries I literally use

```rb
my_model.where('id > ?', last_entry).limit(1000)

# then I set last_entry again, and keep repeating the process

last_entry = my_model.last.id
```

But this seems like an overkill, and doesn't seem right.

Is there any better or easier way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails has the [`find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) method that does exactly what you try to do manually. It loads all records from the database in batches of 1000.

```
MyModel.find_each do |instance|
  # do something with this instance, for example, write into the CVS file
end
```

Comment: Yes. That's it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has an `offset` method that you can combine with `limit`.

```rb
my_model = MyModel.limit(1000).offset(1000)
```

You can see the API documentation here: https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/offset

Hope that helps :)